# Swift Automatic Push Notification with Geolocation

Tags: php, ios, swift, push-notification

i need to integrate push notifications in my app.. i saw a lot of tutorial but any helped me cause i need to do something more difficult. In fact i need that the system send a push notification to all user automatic when a news will publish in the database. example: this is the response i get from database

> {"news":[{"id":"36","type":"news","title":"This is test for Pune","city":"Pune","description":"Test offer for pune city","image":"http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/01.png"},{"id":"35","type":"news","title":"final test for offer","city":"Mumbai","description":"Test description","image":"http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/IMG_0421.JPG"},{"id":"31","type":"news","title":"new test","city":"Mumbai","description":"yes its a test msg","image":"http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/Chrysanthemum.jpg"},{"id":"30","type":"news","title":"This is a test news","city":"Mumbai","description":"Test description","image":"http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/1.jpg"}]}

here we have 4 news..So if i publish another news it will be 5 and the system send a push with the title of that news... is it possible ? if yes wich service i can use? Parse? or a phpserver?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. I am using it using node.js. You should also need to create APNS provisioning certificate for using this service and link for how to create [APNS certificate](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). Following is the sample code for APNS:

```
 var apn  = require("apn")

 var apnError = function(err){
      console.log("APN Error:", err);
 }

 var options = {
     "cert": "cert.pem",
     "key":  "key.pem",
     "passphrase": null,
     "gateway": "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
     "port": 2195,
     "enhanced": true,
     "cacheLength": 5
    };
   options.errorCallback = apnError;

   var feedBackOptions = {
       "batchFeedback": true,
       "interval": 300
   };

   var apnConnection, feedback;

   module.exports = {
       init : function(){
         apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

          feedback = new apn.Feedback(feedBackOptions);
          feedback.on("feedback", function(devices) {
          devices.forEach(function(item) {
            //TODO Do something with item.device and item.time;
             });
        });
   },

   send : function (params){
        var myDevice, note;

        myDevice = new apn.Device(params.token);
        note = new apn.Notification();

        note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires   1 hour from now.
        note.badge = 1;
        note.sound = "ping.aiff";
        note.alert = params.message;
        note.payload = {'messageFrom': params.from};

        if(apnConnection) {
              apnConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);
        }
      }
  }
```

You can find many sample code online for node.js APNS server.

This [Link](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs) or [Link](https://github.com/argon/node-apn) for example.

[Link1](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/)  / [Link 2](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) for notification using PHP

In APNS you can send the title "This is test for Pune" and when user received this "application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:" function in your app delegate will be called and you app will open.

You have to create a View in your app to show the list of notification. User will select a particular notification and then you have fetch the all the news data from your server and show this to user.

Comment: To using APNS service you should be enrolled to Apple developer program or enterprise program or other apple programs which will avail this service to you.

Comment: yes sure thank you fort that... but do you know how i can do that ? so is better with a php server?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Its up to your requirement, if you are comfortable with PHP.

Comment: ok thank you, but how i can connect to the database and say to send the push when there is a new news? i don't think that code does it

Comment: and no i'm not too comfortable with php :(

Comment: Which db you are using?